Getting weired output Image on inference
I've tried to inference upscaling model on image in flutter.
But I cant able to get output correctly.
Low Scaled image:

Output Image:

Some Log:
flutter: Image converted to normalized Float32List
flutter: Image normalized successfully.
flutter: Input tensor created successfully.
flutter: Output Shape: 1, 3, 804, 1428

Whole Code
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late OrtSession ortSession;
  img.Image? selectedImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    OrtEnv.instance.init();
    debugPrint("ORT Environment initialized");
    initializeModel();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    OrtEnv.instance.release();
    super.dispose();
  }
  Future<void> initializeModel() async {
    final sessionOptions = OrtSessionOptions();
    const assetFileName = 'assets/4xSPANkendata_fp32.onnx';
    final rawAssetFile = await rootBundle.load(assetFileName);
    final bytes = rawAssetFile.buffer.asUint8List();
    ortSession = OrtSession.fromBuffer(bytes, sessionOptions);
    debugPrint("Model initialized");
  }

  Future<void> inference() async {
    if (selectedImage == null) {
      debugPrint('No image selected');
      return;
    }

    Float32List preprocessedImage =
        NormalizeImage.imageToNormalizedFloat32List(selectedImage!);
    final shape = [1, 3, selectedImage!.height, selectedImage!.width];

    debugPrint('Image normalized successfully.');

    final inputOrt =
        OrtValueTensor.createTensorWithDataList(preprocessedImage, shape);

    final inputs = {'input': inputOrt};

    debugPrint('Input tensor created successfully.');

    final runOptions = OrtRunOptions();
    final outputs = await ortSession.runAsync(runOptions, inputs);

    inputOrt.release();
    runOptions.release();

    outputs?.forEach((element) {
      final outputValue = element?.value;

      if (outputValue is List<List<List<List<double>>>>) {
        img.Image generatedImage = generateImageFromOutput(outputValue);
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Dialog(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: generatedImage.width.toDouble(),
                height: generatedImage.height.toDouble(),
                child: Image.memory(
                  Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(generatedImage)),
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        debugPrint("Output is of unknown type");
      }
      element?.release();
    });
  }
  img.Image generateImageFromOutput(List<List<List<List<double>>>> output) {
    final batchSize = output.length;
    final channels = output[0].length;
    final height = output[0][0].length;
    final width = output[0][0][0].length;

    debugPrint("Output Shape: $batchSize, $channels, $height, $width");

    img.Image imgData = img.Image(width, height);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int r = (output[0][0][y][x] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255); // Assume RGB order
        int g = (output[0][1][y][x] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        int b = (output[0][2][y][x] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
        imgData.setPixelRgba(x, y, r, g, b);
      }
    }
    return imgData;
  }
  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Image Inference'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (selectedImage != null)
              Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(selectedImage!))),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickImage,
              child: const Text('Select Image'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: inference,
              child: const Text('Run Inference'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Normalize Class
class NormalizeImage {
  static Float32List imageToNormalizedFloat32List(Image image) {
    final int height = image.height;
    final int width = image.width;

    Float32List float32Image = Float32List(3 * height * width);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        final int pixelIndex = (i * width + j) * 3;
        final int pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);

        float32Image[pixelIndex] = getRed(pixel) / 255.0;
        float32Image[pixelIndex + 1] = getGreen(pixel) / 255.0;
        float32Image[pixelIndex + 2] = getBlue(pixel) / 255.0;
      }
    }
    debugPrint("Image converted to normalized Float32List");
    return float32Image;
  }

}

I think the problem is mostly in generateImageFromOutput method.
I also tried to inference in python and its working correctly:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as rt
import torch
import time

# Load the ONNX model with CUDA execution provider
sess = rt.InferenceSession('4xSPANkendata_fp32.onnx')
print("loaded model.")

# Load the input image
img = cv2.imread('xterArt.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


# Convert BGR to RGB and transpose dimensions
in_mat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
in_mat = np.transpose(in_mat, (2, 1, 0))[np.newaxis]
in_mat = in_mat.astype(np.float32)
in_mat = in_mat / 255

# Start time for measuring inference time
start_time = time.time()

# Get input and output names
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name

print("Input name: ", input_name)
print("Output name: ", output_name)


# Convert input to torch tensor and move it to GPU
in_mat = torch.tensor(in_mat)

# Run inference
out_mat = sess.run([output_name], {input_name: in_mat.cpu().numpy()})[0]


# Measure and print elapsed time
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print('Inference time: ',elapsed_time)
# Save the output image
out_mat = (out_mat.squeeze().transpose((2, 1, 0)) * 255).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
output_img = cv2.cvtColor(out_mat, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imwrite('outpust.jpg', out_mat)
print("Output image saved.")




Wrong memory layout of the image?
